# What is the best way to represent 'N' no. of Products in 'M' no. of warehouses with the quantities included

Tags: entity-relationship

I want to make relationship between Product entity and Warehouse(location) Entity as you can see in the picture below.

But the problem is the Quantity since the quantity differs in each warehouse and for each product i am not sure if its correct way since in most of the class diagrams for eg. doctrine2.5 there is no mapping class diagram simply annotation would do.

I know i can add extra column in the product entity but what if there are many warehouses i have not seen any practical with many warehouses usually there are large warehouses(space).

What is the best way to represent 'N' no. of Products in 'M' no. of warehouses with the quantities included.

[My ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q37jc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In table Product_Location, I assume that the primary key is a combination of ProductId and LocationId, and not only one of that Id.

If that is the case, I don't see why you cannot have different quantity for a particular product in different locations.

For example:
Product A is stored in warehouse X and warehouse Y.  The quantity of product A in warehouse X is 10. The quantity of product A in warehouse Y is 20.  Thus, the content of table Product_Location will be:

A - X - 10 and A - Y - 20.

Hope this help.

Comment: So there should be an extra class for product_location with quantity??